# Mock MessageBox using Prig

Tags: c#, mocking

I wish to mock MessageBox from System.Windows.Forms.
Using Prig if possible.

If possible please add the steps to setup, as that has been difficult to achieve.

I doing it the way it is described on github link, so after 'Add Prig assembly for mscorlib', and then same for 'Sysyem.windows.Form', adding the required indirection settings to both of them. After I build the project, sometimes I get following messages in error list tab [image]

with no PMessageBox class.

If I do the same for Datetime class, it works perfectly.

UPDATED:
This is how my System.Windows.Forms.v4.0.30319.v4.0.0.0.prig lookslike:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  ========================== EXAMPLE 1 ==========================
  PM> $methods = Find-IndirectionTarget datetime get_Now
  PM> $methods

  Method
  ======
  System.DateTime get_Now()


  PM> $methods[0] | Get-IndirectionStubSetting | clip
  PM>

  ========================== EXAMPLE 2 ==========================
  PM> $methods = Find-IndirectionTarget datetime CompareTo
  PM> $methods

  Method
  ======
  Int32 CompareTo(System.Object)
  Int32 CompareTo(System.DateTime)


  PM> $methods[0] | Get-IndirectionStubSetting | clip
  PM>

  Then, paste the clipboard content to between the tags 'stubs'.
```

-->

```
<stubs>
  <!--<add name="NowGet" alias="NowGet">
    <RuntimeMethodInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" z:Id="1" z:FactoryType="MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Type="System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Assembly="0" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection">
      <Name z:Id="2" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">get_Now</Name>
      <AssemblyName z:Id="3" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">mscorlib</AssemblyName>
      <ClassName z:Id="4" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.DateTime</ClassName>
      <Signature z:Id="5" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.DateTime get_Now()</Signature>
      <Signature2 z:Id="6" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.DateTime get_Now()</Signature2>
      <MemberType z:Id="7" z:Type="System.Int32" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">8</MemberType>
      <GenericArguments i:nil="true" xmlns="" />
    </RuntimeMethodInfo>
  </add>-->
  <!--<add name="CompareToObject" alias="CompareToObject">
    <RuntimeMethodInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" z:Id="1" z:FactoryType="MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Type="System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Assembly="0" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection">
      <Name z:Id="2" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">CompareTo</Name>
      <AssemblyName z:Id="3" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">mscorlib</AssemblyName>
      <ClassName z:Id="4" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.DateTime</ClassName>
      <Signature z:Id="5" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">Int32 CompareTo(System.Object)</Signature>
      <Signature2 z:Id="6" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.Int32 CompareTo(System.Object)</Signature2>
      <MemberType z:Id="7" z:Type="System.Int32" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">8</MemberType>
      <GenericArguments i:nil="true" xmlns="" />
    </RuntimeMethodInfo>
  </add>-->
  <!-- 
      PMessageBox.ShowString().Body = 
          text => 
          {   
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          };
  -->
  <add name="ShowString" alias="ShowString">
    <RuntimeMethodInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" z:Id="1" z:FactoryType="MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Type="System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder" z:Assembly="0" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection">
      <Name z:Id="2" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">Show</Name>
      <AssemblyName z:Id="3" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</AssemblyName>
      <ClassName z:Id="4" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox</ClassName>
      <Signature z:Id="5" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult Show(System.String)</Signature>
      <Signature2 z:Id="6" z:Type="System.String" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult Show(System.String)</Signature2>
      <MemberType z:Id="7" z:Type="System.Int32" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">8</MemberType>
      <GenericArguments i:nil="true" xmlns="" />
    </RuntimeMethodInfo>
  </add>
</stubs>
```

Updated:
Its working now.
Removed the indirection settings from mscorlib.v4.0.30319.v4.0.0.0.prig
Acc. to link https://github.com/urasandesu/Prig/issues/97

It still didn't remove messages from error list, but somehow I have the class PMessageBox created.
I have done these settings before , somehow it worked this time.
If I find anything, I will update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing to [this](https://github.com/urasandesu/Prig/wiki/Test-using-MessageBox-by-Typemock-Isolator) articles ,You can do this on [Visual studio IDE](https://www.visualstudio.com/)

```
 [Test]
 public void MessageBoxShow_should_be_callable_indirectly()
 {
    using (new IndirectionsContext())
   {
    // Arrange
    var mockMessageBox = new Mock<IndirectionFunc<string, DialogResult>>();
    mockMessageBox.Setup(_ => _(string.Empty)).Returns(DialogResult.OK);

    PMessageBox.ShowString().Body = mockMessageBox.Object;

    // Act
    MessageBox.Show("This is a message");

    // Assert
    mockMessageBox.Verify(_ => _("This is a message"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for reply. My issue has been, after I add  indirection settings to System.Windows.Forms.v4.0.30319.v4.0.0.0.prig. And if I build the project, I don't get PMessageBox class. Instead I get messages in Error List:
Could not find schema information for the element 'Signature2'
Could not find schema information for the element 'section'
Could not find schema information for the element 'prig'